# How can I cope with a two-peak histogram with one flat and one steep peak?

Tags: histogram

See this screenshot:
[image: Histogram]

The not-yet-processed image depicts a rural landscape right after sunset. It looks like this: [image]

Its parameteres are: Canon EOS 70D + EF 24–105 mm f/4 L IS; ISO 800; 1/13"; f/6.3; +1/3 EV; 47 mm.

**UPDATE:** Here is the original image together with the histogram in darktable: [image: Histogram in darktable before adjustment], and here is the image after white / gray / black point adjustment: [image: Histogram in darktable after adjustment]

Comment: What is your notion of what it means to "resolve a ... histogram"?

Comment: I meant to adjust the brightness curve with maximum contrast without enhancing noise too much.

Comment: can you post an image you want to replicate? or "i want look like that, here is my starting material"

Comment: The histogram matches the image. It's what I would expect the histogram to look like. What bothers you about the histogram?

Comment: You can quite aggressively force the histogram to be full-scale by pushing the curves… but it doesn't necessarily improve the image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/19Zfh.jpg What is it about the histogram that needs 'fixing'?

Comment: Why do you think this specific shape needs any special treatment?

Comment: Well, it's not the shape of the histogram, which bothers me, but the fact that there are regions in this photo, which are definitely too dark, as well as rather bright sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get trim the flat or empty ends of the histogram or levels. There are many great videos and tutorials on it.

Here's fixing the levels in photoshop on your photo from your post. You drag the pointers in to where there's more info than a flat line. You'll also need to restore saturation and contrast. I didn't do that to the example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Save for me not using Photoshop, this was the solution (see my updated question). Thank you!

Comment: Is it just me or is there a halo around the trees?

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few different ways to stretch the contrast of a low dynamic range image, all with slightly different tradeoffs in the actual effects (and side effects). One of the most common is what Photoshop calls "levels" - you essentially choose what levels in the histogram you want to call black, white, and a mid-gray. [Here's](https://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/levels.htm) a decent tutorial, based on Photoshop's version of that tool. Depending on what toolset you are using, other adjustments would be the brightness/saturation/contrast group, gamma correction or curves, or something like Ansel Adams' zone system (which [darktable](http://darktable.org/) implements quite nicely).

No matter which method you use, you have to be careful to avoid unwanted side effects, like posterization/banding, unnatural color changes, enhancing noise too much, or making the image look artificial. You'll have to play with the relevant parameters to see what is acceptable to you.

Comment: I'm using Darktable and Gimp.

Comment: In that case, personally, I would start with the Exposure module - set the exposure to somewhere between +2 and +3, it looks like to me - just enough so the histogram touches the right edge - and then drag the black point to the right until the histogram starts to touch the left edge as well. Once I was satisfied with that, I would play with the Zone System module to redistribute various luminance bands a bit.